# NodeJS Debian 8

Tags: node.js, debian

I installed nodejs with nvm on my Debian 8 but my Netbeans 8.2 does not want to work with that node so  I installed the nodejs with apt-get which is now in usr/bin. How switch  the PATH of the node to  usr/bin/node

Comment: `export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"` try this

Comment: Many thanks. I found that I simply need to switch off the nvm  in .profile and restart.

Comment: well in that case I put it as answer

Answer (score 0):

run this command in your terminal and restart the terminal.

```
source ~/.profile
```